# Why it'll abort when I add `RUN ln -sf /dev/stderr /var/log/mysql/error.log` to mysql dockerfile?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Why it'll abort when I add `RUN ln -sf /dev/stderr /var/log/mysql/error.log` to 
mysql dockerfile?

Answer (score 0):

Try this if it's works:

```
RUN cat /dev/null >> /var/log/mysql/error.log \
    && ln -sf /dev/stderr /var/log/mysql/error.log
```

My quess is this log file not created for some reason.

Comment: May be not works. Because it links from /dev/stderr to error.log. Whether error.log exits will be right.